# Creating a command history pipe, how do I get rid of the line feed passed by ack?

Tags: linux, bash

I am manually recreating bash's history expansion for reasons beyond the scope of this question. This is to say, I know that this functionality exists with another bash method, but the way I structure my bash history, each session gets its own session history file, i.e.

```
HISTFILE="${HOME}/.history/$(date -u +%Y/%m/%d.%H.%M.%S)_${HOSTNAME_SHORT}_$$"
```

requires that I build my own history search functions.

I have written the following functions:

```
function historysearch {
  ack "$1" ~/.history
}

function historycopy {
  mycopy=$(historysearch $1 | ack $2 | rev | cut -d: -f1 | rev)
  echo ${mycopy%\\n} | pbcopy
}
```

Usage goes as follows:

```
$ historysearch foo


...
~/.history/2015/10/10.14.53.34_user-5_16778
6:hexedit assets/wav/foo_mu.wav
13:hexedit assets/wav/foo_mu.wav
...
```

Having identified the command I want, I then

```
$ historycopy foo 778:13
```

where the second argument is the last three digits of the name of the session history followed by `:` and then the digits associated with the command I want. The above copies the command I want to my system clipboard. Unfortunately, it does so with a carriage even when I run the string replace command `${mycopy%\\n}` within the function. This is the rub ...

If I paste the command into the terminal it immediately executes. I would much prefer to have the command copied to the clipboard so that I would be able to paste it, alter it if necessary and then manually execute.

How do I get rid of the line feed at the end of the string passed to `pbcopy`?

Update: It appears that my string replace command *was* removing the line feed from `ack` but then `echo` was adding another line feed. Resolved with `-n` flag.

Comment: Do not confuse _carriage return_ with _line feed_. _Carriage return_ is normally used for `\r`, and _line feed_ for `\n`. What you want to remove is a _line feed_, not a _carriage return_, which is normally used in Windows.

Comment: Thanks fixed in title of question.

Comment: Why do you need your own history search? Couldn't you just use `history -r` to read the new value of `HISTFILE` at shell startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` adds a line feed at the end. To avoid this, use `echo -n`

Comment: There it is. Much obliged.

Comment: Or use `printf` which is generally better behaved.